# At what point does a bunch of ingredients become a medicine?

Tags: medical, covid-19, is-x-legal, drugs, vaccination

In most if not all countries it is illegal to sell unlicensed medicines and medical treatments.  It is however legal to sell the reagents, equipment and instructions to individuals for them to create the medicine or perform the procedure.  Is it defined where the line is between these situations?

Two fairly high profile examples of this are:

- CRISPR

  - There are [available kits](https://www.the-odin.com/diy-crispr-kit/) that allow you to perform CRISPR/Cas9 gene editing.
- COVID vaccine

  - There is an open source method for [producing a nasal COVID-19 vaccine](https://radvac.org/).

The RaDVaC vaccine is a good example.  Currently it is only available as a free open source ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) and [OCL-P v1.1](https://opencovidpledge.org/licenses__trashed/v1-1-ocl-p/)) white paper, and all the ingredients and equipment must be sourced individually.  I presume from the CRISPR example it would be legal to sell "kits" with all the necessary items.  Just this step would cover most of the "methods" section of the instructions, as that is dominated by the choice of epitopes.  I could probably perform a number of further steps, such as preparation of the appropriate dilutions of reagents and possibly creation of the the chitosan nanoparticles, prior to shipping.  I could perhaps reduce the instructions from a 90 page document to "mix this powder with water, wait an hour, spray it up your nose".

Is it possible to work out *a priori* which of these "kits" would be legal to sell?  Any jurisdiction would be interesting, I guess if this is on the internet "somewhere with an extradition treaty with the US" is probably the important factor.

If I need to say it, I think doing this would be a really bad idea from a public health standpoint for many fairly obvious reasons.  Perhaps not as bad as selling CRISPR kits though.

Comment: For US patent law, it applies when you complete something that the patent applies to. So if part 1, part 2, part 3 each don't match a patent, but I can put them together and the patent applies to the combination, it applies at the moment I put the parts together. On one hand you might except something similar in similar situations, on the other hand this was added to US patent laws because companies tried to get around patents by shipping an invention in easily combined parts.

Comment: I don't think there are "unlicensed medicines" in the US but there are in the UK, instead there are "unapproved drugs". Are you specifically asking about UK licensing?

Comment: It's not only a matter of the physical substances you are selling, but also of how you market them - in particular whether they're sold as a treatment for a disease.  If I sell peaches with a label that says "you can bake these into a peach pie, and it will taste delicious", I'm fine.  If I sell those same peaches with a label that says "you can boil the pits into a syrup, and it might help with your cancer", I'm in serious legal trouble.

Comment: @user6726 I am imagining this could be sold online.  I would be particularly interested in the UK and US.  I am more familiar with the UK terminology.

Comment: In the US, the Food and Drug Administration, or FDA, lists medicines. They might have lists of ones that are no longer approved. They also list devices, which require approval. A kit for CRISPR might be a device and so require FDA review and approval.